# Is it possible to have two different Azure accounts access one implementation of MSAL Angular for a SPA?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I have been using MSAL Angular for a while now and our general implementation is as follows:

- We have an app registration in Azure that is configured for the SPA.
- Users are assigned access in Azure AD.
- These details are then used as part of the build process for the app. Things like client ID, redirect URIs etc.

Is it possible to set it up in a way that allows 2 different app registrations from 2 different Azure accounts to access the one SPA?

I have not seen any documentation for this kind of implementation and the fact the configs only take strings and not an array I am not sure if it can be done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It sounds like you might want to take a look at multi-tenant applications.

Comment: We are trying to allow 2 different Azure ADs to access our 1 SPA. Are you suggesting something like this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: Each app registration is unique and is associated with a specific Azure AD tenant. The client ID and redirect URIs are specific to each app registration, and they cannot be shared between different app registrations.

- If the SPA app is configured as multitenant then the other tenant users can access the SPA app, but not other tenant apps can access it.
- The Azure AD configs only accepts string not an array and hence you cannot allow 2 different app registrations from 2 different Azure accounts to access the one SPA.

*But you can allow the access of users from 2 different Azure accounts to access the one SPA.*

For this you have to **configure SPA as Multitenant application**:

[image]

Granted API permissions:

[image]

***Now you can sign-in with different Azure tenant users:***

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://xxx/spa.access
&state=12345
&code_challenge=CodeChallenge
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

[image]

[image]

I generated **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:api://xxx/spa.access
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
code_verifier:S256
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

[image]